# Reading values from text file for map into my application

Tags: android, maps, android-maps-v2

Right now I am trying to allow a user to select a location which will take them to it on a map. This works fine, however it is hard coded. What I want to be able to do is read in values I have stored in a text file which will then take the user to the lat and lon values on my map.

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {    // map is loaded but not laid out yet
    this.map = map;
    // code to run when the map has loaded

    double lat, lon;

    if (city.equals("Dublin"))
    {
        lat = 53.343908;
        lon = -6.267554;
    }
    else if (city.equals("Cork"))
    {
        lat= 51.892751;
        lon= -8.491542;
    }
    else
    {
        lat=0;
        lon=0;
    }

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                    .title("")
    );

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

}
```

This is currently how I am doing it. I can supply the rest or more of my code if neccessary. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I read it. You wrote what you want. But you did not describe problems doing so. Reading a text file line by line is pretty standard so why dont you post that code to begin with? Or isnt that your problem? If not then what is the problem?

Comment: So many questions in your question. What is your problem exactly? What have you tried so far as we're not going to code your app for you?

Comment: Many questions? I dont see one!

Comment: Let's say 'potential' questions then, as it implies to: read a file, display a ui for the user to choose a location based on the info from the file, redirect the user to the map, display the selected location on the map.

Comment: But still, it looks like OP asks for an entire app! :D

Comment: Are you aware of a post by `m.rajabi` about the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583634/how-read-a-file-from-storage-and-edit-text-of-the-file-and-add-to-code?noredirect=1#comment82140094_47583634

Comment: I had answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509681/reading-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-text-file/47511628#47511628